# Precompile Assets when deploying Rails app onto Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

My Heroku application has a lot of difficulty on 2 to 4 visits after deploying. It appears the CSS and JavaScript assets are generating during this time and it's timing out.

The precompiling with the Asset Pipeline appears to be working fine (once completed) as sequential visits render pages within 3-5 seconds. The Rails 4 app is hosted on Heroku and the assets are included into the application dynamically, example:

```
<!-- Styles -->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "themes/#{theme}/main", media: "all" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "fonts/#{theme}/font", media: 'all' %>
```

When deploying to Heroku, I get no errors for precompiling.

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Asset precompilation completed (2.95s)
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to precompile the assets manually when you push new versions to Heroku? I've never used the asset pipeline on Heroku, just always precompiled my assets before upload. Is this an option?

Comment: I don't precompile the assets manually. I could do it before pushing to Heroku but that task could be forgotten (human error), and we're about to move towards a CI server. Thus an automated option is preferred.

Comment: What's a `CI` server?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration

Comment: I have a suspicion that it's failing to precompile due to the dynamic themes.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple once I found the options required. I had to add the following in `config/environments/staging.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css.sass )
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css.scss )
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js )
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js.coffee )
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js.coffee.erb )
```

First time to deploy took 227s, the next deploy took 2.93s to precompile assets.